# inheritance and private variables C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Hello I am just getting started with C++ and I am wondering why I am getting this error: C2248: Undergraduate: Undergraduate cannot access private variable in class 'Undergraduate'.

Here is my **student.h** class which Undergraduate inherits from

```
#ifndef _STUDENT_H_
#define _STUDENT_H_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    // private local variables
    string fname, lname;
    int grade;
    int edu;

public:
    Student(string f, string l, int grade, int edu); // constructor
    string getFirstName(); // accessor
    string getLastName(); // accessor
    int getGrade(); // accessor
    int getEdu(); // accessor

    // Q1: Friend Function Change Grade
    // Declare a friend function named changeGrade which takes 2 parameters and has no return value.
    // The first parameter is a pointer to a Student, and the second is an integer.
    // See the helper function in hw09.cpp for proper use of this function.
    friend void changeGrade(Student *s, int newGrade){}
    virtual void displayInfo(){ }
};

#endif // _STUDENT_H_
```

**Student.cpp**

```
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student(string f, string l, int g, int e) {
    fname = f;
    lname = l;
    grade = g;
    edu = e;
}

string Student::getFirstName() { // accessor implimentation
    return fname;
}

string Student::getLastName() {
    return lname;
}

int Student::getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

int Student::getEdu() {
    return edu;
}
```

and finally **Undergraduate.h**

```
// Q2a : Create Undergraduate Class

// Create a child class of the Student class named 'Undergraduate'
// See the add function in hw09.cpp for proper use of this function.
class Undergraduate : public Student{
private:
    Undergraduate(string f, string l, int grade, int edu): Student(f,l,grade,edu){

    }
    virtual void displayInfo(){ }
};
// Declare constructor which accepts the same 4 parameters as the parent class Student.
// Pass the 4 parameters to the super constructor in the Student class.
```

Now I understand that private variables can only be accessed by that member of the class but the homework is asking me to use the same parameters as the parent class this is what is confusing me so is there a way around this I couldn't really find anything online similar enough to this particular assignment.

Comment: So is the error location actually somewhere in the code you posted? My guess would be not. Without actually seeing the line having the error, I would guess the issue is that you have declared the constructor of `Undergraduate` as private but then try to create an `Undergraduate` object somewhere else.

Comment: Make the variables `protected`, rather than `private`

Comment: @Chiel: He does not try to access private variables from the base class, he calls the public constructor.

Comment: @Chiel no, protected data is bad.

Comment: Posted code [compiles cleanly](http://ideone.com/3TNB60). Your problem is elsewhere. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_STUDENT_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: @n.m Why are protected variables bad?

Comment: Bad for maintainability, create unnecessary coupling between base and derived. Not as bad as public data obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Since yours `Undergraduate(string f, string l, int grade, int edu): Student(f,l,grade,edu)` constructor is private, how do you instantiate this class?